# input type Time in Angular return value as time in mysql not working

Tags: html, mysql, angular, spring-boot, phpmyadmin

**Angular**

in **model Reglep**  debut!:Time;
in **ReglepComponent.ts**   reglep: Reglep = new Reglep();
in **ReglepComponent.html**   <input type="time" class ="form-control" id = "debut"  [(ngModel)] = "reglep.debut" name = "debut">

**Mysql**
column debut type=Time
**springboot**
import java.sql.Time;
private Time debut;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to save value of input type time from angular into  mysql column type time